# Scraping with BeautifuldSoup to csv

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code does not crash when I ran it.  The output file **flyingmag.csv**  is populated but not as I want.  I want to add **div class="elementor-widget-container” > h2** and  **div class="elementor-widget-container” > h3** so that both Airplane manufacturer and airplane model are included in the output.
I want really the records to be in a traditional excel **row** format as well as scrape **all aircraft manufacturers and models**

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request

url = 'https://www.flyingmag.com/2019-buyers-single-engine-piston/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}

with open('flyingmag.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)    
    writer.writerow(['Base_Price','Typically_Equipped_Price','Engine','Horsepower','Propeller','Seats','Length','Height','Wingspan','Wing_Area','Wing_Loading','Power_Loading','Max_Takeoff_Weight','Empty_Weight','Useful_Load','Fuel_Capacity','Max_Operating_Altitude','Max_Rate_of_Climb','Max_Cruise_Speed','Normal_Cruise_Speed','Never_Exceed_Speed','Stall_Speed-Flaps_Up','Stall_Speed-Landing_Configuration','Max_Range','Takeoff_Roll','Takeoff_Distance_Over_50_ft.','Landing_Roll','Landing_Distance_Over_50_ft'])

    while True:
        html = requests.get(url , headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
      
        for row in soup.select('table tbody tr'):
            writer.writerow([c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('td')])
            print(row)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Stop spamming with tags. There's no `pandas` in your code and the page has no pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first work out the number of overarching "sections", or listings as I call them, by locating the h3 headers, which I do with `section:has([data-widget_type="heading.default"])` then loop those and extract the manufacturer. Use `find_next` to move to the actual following sections containing the model and table. All data appears to be present on that single page if you scroll down to bottom.

With respect to headers:

```
td:not([colspan]) strong
```

The `:not([colspan])` is used to exclude the last `Back to Top` row of each table for each listing. This is a "merged cell" with a `colspan` attribute and doesn't contain data you want. You could also have used an `nth-child range` selector. The first (or left most as you view page) and third table columns are used for the headers, and I access these only for the first listing. I checked that these same headers were present in all tables initially. The *space* `strong` is to then select for descendant `strong` elements, which are present for the 1st and 3rd `td` children in each row of the tables.

With respect to row values in csv after headers:

```
td:not([colspan]):nth-child(even)
```

The first part is as per the headers explanation. However, instead of then adding in a descendant combinator with `strong` type selector, I simply used `nth-child(even)`; This selected for the 2nd and 4th columns as desired as these are the even numbered children.

---

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.flyingmag.com/2019-buyers-single-engine-piston')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
listings = soup.select('section:has([data-widget_type="heading.default"])')

with open('flyingmag.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as f:
    
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)    
    
    for num, listing in enumerate(listings):
        
        manufacturer = listing.select_one('[data-widget_type="heading.default"] h2').text
        model = listing.find_next('h3').text
        table = listing.find_next('table')
        
        if num == 0:
            
            row = ['Manufacturer', 'Model']
            row.extend([i.text for i in table.select('td:not([colspan]) strong')])
            writer.writerow(row)
        
        values = [i.text for i in table.select('td:not([colspan]):nth-child(even)')]
        row = [manufacturer, model]
        row.extend(values)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Dear QHarr, many thanks for your insight.  I added "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs".  Only the headers are not lined-up because of the two new fields, both of which are missing.

Comment: oh so sorry... I will quickly amend